# Set max file size while uploading image in ckeditor

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I was trying to restrict max-upload size of the image using this code

```
const onFileUploadRequest = evt => {
  let fileLoader = evt.data.fileLoader;
  if (fileLoader.file.size > max_size) {
     fileLoader.abort ();
    evt.cancel ();
  } else {
    //DO required
    // To prevent the default behavior.
    evt.stop ();
  }
};
```

But ckeditor showing a alert message with undefined text after calling fileLoader.abort() function. IS there any other way to validate image size on ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const onFileUploadRequest = evt => {
  let fileLoader = evt.data.fileLoader;
  if (fileLoader.file.size > max_size) {
     fileLoader.message = "error message"
     fileLoader.abort ();
    evt.cancel ();
  } else {
    //DO required
    // To prevent the default behavior.
    evt.stop ();
  }
};
```

Comment: consider adding an explanation. it makes the code easier to understand.